# Django application handling for multiple tabs

Tags: django, session, tabs

I have a django based application integrated with login. When I open the application for the first tab and login, this tab logs out automatically when the application is opened in another tab of the same browser. When the sessions created for each tab is separate, why this logs out the old tabs. And the behaviour is not consistent too.

I tried to add the settings
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
and this seems to be not working

Comment: How are you authenticating users? Are you using a unique session identifier in URL parameter instead of a cookie?